# Send Transaction to smart contract using web3 ^1.0.0-beta.41 throws parsing error

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to send  to smart contract using this code :

```
  this.myContract.methods.addData(declaration).send({
            from: '0x3b0282D31174B927e102bA71d80dF34F4e596Fc4',
            gas: 12000
        })
```

this code throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'from' on string '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'
```

What is exactly this error means?

Comment: Your gas is too little, absolute minimum is 21k and you will need more when calling a smart contract.

Comment: I tried with gas: 300000 and I got the same error

Comment: Can you share the code of the function `addData`? What is the value of `declaration` variable?

Comment: please see details here https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2341#issuecomment-461534427

Comment: What does your contract looks like? It seems you are trying to send a json object to a solidity method, try sending that a string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in this way -

`web3.eth.contract(contract_abi).new.getData(
    parameter1,
    parameter2  // dont add parameters if you function dont have any
    {
        data: data_company.abiData,
    });
let gas = web3.toHex(300000)
let nonce = web3.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount("0x3b0282D31174B927e102bA71d80dF34F4e596Fc4"))
let transactionObject = {
    gas: gas,
    data: deploy,
    from: "0x3b0282D31174B927e102bA71d80dF34F4e596Fc4",
    nonce: nonce
};`

Comment: Why I have doing it this way ?  what is wrong with my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do like that:

```
  this.myContract.methods.addData(declaration, {
            from: '0x3b0282D31174B927e102bA71d80dF34F4e596Fc4',
            gas: 12000
        }).send()
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to low Gas

Try this:

```
this.contract.methods.addData(declaration).send({
    from: "0x3b0282D31174B927e102bA71d80dF34F4e596Fc4",
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(210000),
    maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('40', 'gwei')),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('40', 'gwei')),
})
.then((receipt)=>console.log(receipt))
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```